# select min value of range [0,44) not in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with an int valued column, which has values between 0 and 43 (both included).

I would like a query that returns the min value of the range [0,44) which is not in the table.

For example:
if the table contains: 3,5, 14. The query should return 0
if the table contains: 0,1, 14. The query should return 2
if the table contains: 0,3, 14. The query should return 1

If the table contains all values, the query should return empty.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Could you provide reason why for example 3,5,14 would yield 0 and 0,1,14 would yield 2? Your example is not that clear to me.

Comment: I hope it - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html will can useful

Comment: @Edper As far as I understood he needs the lowest value which is not in the table. 0 is the minumum but in the second sequence 0 and 1 are present so 2 will be the lowest value not in the column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the value you want is either `0` or 1 greater than a value that exists in the table, you can just do;

```
SELECT MIN(value)
FROM (SELECT 0 value UNION SELECT value+1 FROM MyTable) a
WHERE value < 44 AND value NOT IN (SELECT value FROM MyTable)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab2a6/1).

Comment: Nice, but it looks quadratic to the size of table. Any faster way?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create another table that contains the integers in `[0,43]` and then left join that and look for NULLs, the NULLs will tell you what values are missing.

Suppose you have:

```
create table numbers (n int not null);
```

and this table contains the integers from 0 to 43 (inclusive). If your table is `t` and has a column `n` which holds the numbers of interest, then:

```
select n.n
from numbers n left join t on n.n = t.n
where t.n is null
order by n.n
limit 1
```

should give you the result you're after.

This is a fairly common SQL technique when you're working with a sequence. The most common use is probably calendar tables.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to generate a set of 44 rows with integer values, and then perform an anti-join against the distinct set of values from the table, and the grab the mininum value.

```
SELECT MIN(r.val) AS min_val
  FROM ( SELECT 0 AS val UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 UNION ALL
         SELECT 4 UNION ALL
         SELECT 5 UNION ALL
         -- ... 
         SELECT 44 
       ) r
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT t.int_valued_col
           FROM mytable t
          WHERE t.int_valued_col >= 0
            AND t.int_valued_col <= 43
          GROUP BY t.int_valued_col
       ) v
    ON v.int_valued_col = r.col
 WHERE v.int_valued_col IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit hacky and MySQL-specific:

```
SELECT NULLIF(MAX(IF(val=@min, @min:=(val+1), @min)), @max) as min_empty
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT val
  FROM table1
  -- WHERE val BETWEEN 0 AND 43
  ORDER BY val) as vals, (SELECT @min:=0, @max:=44) as init;
```